# Passing login details to api

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have to pass login detail to may API code.When I pass information like below, I cannot get the success message .The mail or mobile number that i entering is already in db. But I only get the not success message.

```
$scope.doLogin=function(){

    $rootScope.logData=document.getElementById("eorm").value;
    console.log($rootScope.logData);
    var mob=/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    if($rootScope.logData.match(mob)){
        $rootScope.log_type=1;

    }
    else{
        var em=/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9._]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z.]{2,5}$/;
        if($rootScope.logData.match(em)){
            $rootScope.log_type=2;
        }           
    }

    $http.post($rootScope.ajaxurl+"login",{"user_login":$rootScope.logData,"user_login_type":'$rootScope.log_type'},
    {headers:{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}})
    .success(function(response){
       console.log(response,$rootScope.logData,$rootScope.log_type);
       $location.path("app/otp")
    })    
}
```

Comment: Check the content type that the backend expects. The AngularJS framework POSTS data using `Content-Type: application/json`. Setting the content-type to `x-www-form-urlencoded`  is not recommended.

Comment: Still it's not working.My api call only gives the error message.That is, its not going to the success part